# Why does it show the tag's type when I use getElementById method in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I used getElementById method to return the tag's element but it returns the tag's type ?!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id ="textlabel"></p>
  
    <script>
      function bonef(){
        var a = 
  document.getElementById("textlabel");
        var b = "1";
        a.innerHTML += b;
      }
    </script>

    <button onclick="bonef();">1</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

It shows "[object HTMLParagraphElement]1" but I want "1" !

Comment: then access the `value` -- `document.getElementById("textlabel").value`

Comment: It shows this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined.

Comment: If you want `"1"` then just do `var b = "1";` right? `a + "1"` stringifies the HTML element which you almost never want to do. You're querying it so you can call `.innerHTML` on it.

Comment: Please specify what are you trying to do. What is the meaning of adding 1 to the inner html. what is your goal

Comment: Yes, but I wanna be able to write either 11 or 1111.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. You could maybe make two buttons, one triggers `11` and the other triggers `1111`, or add a user input, or use `.innerHTML += b` or something like that so you can click multiple times to get multiple 1s.

Comment: I just want to write 1,11,111 and etc with button in text field(p tag).

Comment: Okay, did you try my suggestions? Now you want commas? Unclear.

Comment: I am now able to write multiply, but...

Comment: It is still object html.....

Comment: You changed `var b = a+"1";` to `var b = "1";`?

Comment: I appreciate ggorlen and nouhomsi for help.

Comment: Now the question has no value because you changed it to work !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use getElementById any more, Instead use the querySelector:

```
let label = document.querySelector("#textlabel");
```

I think this is what you want to do:

```
function bonef(){
   let a = document.querySelector("#textlabel")
    a.innerHTML += "1";
  }
```

Comment: What's the problem with `document.getElementById`?

Comment: There is no problem with it, OP seems to be a beginner so I gave him a good practice syntax. If you see I wrote the code he asked for

Comment: We'll see--the question is unclear, so if you happen to guess OP's intent, I'm not sure it offers a whole lot of value to the site as a resource, and doing so makes it harder to close and delete the question if OP never bothers to edit the post and clarify their intent. If there's nothing wrong with `getElementById` then I don't see why the emphasis on changing it to `querySelector`. Given that OP is a beginner, this seems like it only adds more confusion.